# WPF: Ensure that button have the same Width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've currently a `StackPanel` with several `Button` inside.
The content of the `Button` are dynamic, so I don't know their size.

Each `Button`has different margins.

I would like to have all my buttons having the same width(without counting the Margin in it).

Here is an example:

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Margin="3" Content="{Binding PreviousButtonText, ElementName=CurrentControl}" Command="{Binding GoToPreviousPageCommand}"/>
            <Button Margin="3,3,8,3"  Content="{Binding NextButtonText, ElementName=CurrentControl}" Command="{Binding GoToNextPageCommand}" Visibility="{Binding IsLastPage, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibleConverter}, ConverterParameter=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Button Margin="3,3,8,3"  Content="{Binding FinishButtonText, ElementName=CurrentControl}" Command="{Binding FinishCommand}" Visibility="{Binding IsLastPage, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibleConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Button Margin="8,3,3,3" Content="{Binding CancelButtonText, ElementName=CurrentControl}" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Since I need to have the same width, but not count the Margin in it, I can't use `UniformGrid`(Or Grid with `SharedSizeGroup`).

The goal is to do have all buttons occupying the "max width" required by one of the button.

This has to be done in XAML, no code behind.
Another thing, the Text inside the buttons can be changed on runtime.

Any idea how to do this?

**Edit** it seems that many people didn't understood that I need a Button with the same width, not a button+his margin having the same width.

All your solutions gives something like this: where you can clearly see that the button doesn't have the same size(I increased the "8" margin value to better show the issue).
[image]

Here is what I would like to achieve(I cheated with putting some fixed values):
[image]

Comment: create a `Grid` with `width * ` and `Column width` as `* `

Comment: @AbinMathew Except he's got it aligned Right which would scrunch the columns if it was a grid.

Comment: Has to be done in XAML?   Why?

Comment: Because xaml is seksi. :D

Comment: WIthout codebehind I think you will have some problems, I would use MinWidth and bind it to a property set at Runtime (especially if you change the text at Runtime).

Comment: @AbinMathew Will not work, this allow a fixed size for the child(so including the margin)

Comment: @Frisbee Well I've my reasons, because it's a challenge, because it might be used in customControl, because it's really a design thing, and we would like to be able to do this in blend. Additionally, there is many values that are bound to the object which will influence the size(like the size of the text, min/max size of the user control, and the binding should take care of all of this

Comment: There must be some broader context on why you need this width behavior and depending on your context and your goal you might find other solution than the stack panel. Can you explain the context and reason of this particular need? For example I would create a new Button class which inherits standard wpf Button and share its size among its instances from a certain container (Stack Panel in your case).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small class which inherits the standard WPF Button control. It ensures that controls within same container share same width when any of the buttons changes its size and becomes the one with max width.
However, this is only a prrof of concept and you should complete it accordingly to your containers (maybe are not just StackPanels), maybe to treat errors with exceptions, not `return;` statements and so on.

**Later edit**: you specified that no code-behind solution should be here. Are new control classes forbidden too in your requirements? If yes, this doesn't apply then.

```
internal class WidthButton : Button
{
    private static Dictionary<Panel, List<Button>> _containers = new Dictionary<Panel, List<Button>>();

    public WidthButton()
    {
        this.Initialized += WidthButton_Initialized;
        this.SizeChanged += WidthButton_SizeChanged;
    }

    void WidthButton_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as Panel;
        if (parent == null) return;

        var thisButton = sender as Button;
        if (thisButton == null) return;

        if (!_containers.ContainsKey(parent))
        {
           _containers.Add(parent, new List<Button>()); 
        }

        if (!_containers[parent].Contains(thisButton))
        {
            _containers[parent].Add(thisButton);
        }
    }

    void WidthButton_SizeChanged(object sender, System.Windows.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var thisButton = sender as Button;
        if (thisButton == null) return;

        var containerPair = _containers.FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.Value.Contains(thisButton));
        if (containerPair.Value == null) return;

        var maxWidth = containerPair.Value.Max(btn => btn.ActualWidth);
        containerPair.Value.ForEach(btn => btn.Width = maxWidth);
    }
}
```

**Later later edit**: here is an example which uses an attached behavior (potential memory leak as there is no unsubscribing to SizeChanged event)

```
internal class WidthBehavior
{
    private static Dictionary<string, List<FrameworkElement>> _scopes = new Dictionary<string, List<FrameworkElement>>();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WidthShareScopeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "WidthShareScope", typeof (string), typeof (WidthBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var elem = dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;
        if (elem == null) return;

        var scope = dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue as string;
        if (scope == null) return;

        if (!_scopes.ContainsKey(scope))
        {
            _scopes.Add(scope, new List<FrameworkElement>());
        }

        if (!_scopes[scope].Contains(elem))
        {
            _scopes[scope].Add(elem);
            elem.SizeChanged += elem_SizeChanged;
        }
    }

    static void elem_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var elem = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (elem == null) return;

        var scope = GetWidthShareScope(elem);
        ArrangeScope(scope);
    }

    private static void ArrangeScope(string scope)
    {
        if (!_scopes.ContainsKey(scope)) return;

        var list = _scopes[scope];

        var maxWidth = list.Max(elem => elem.ActualWidth);
        list.ForEach(elem => elem.Width = maxWidth);
    }

    public static void SetWidthShareScope(DependencyObject element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(WidthShareScopeProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetWidthShareScope(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (string) element.GetValue(WidthShareScopeProperty);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

        <Button Margin="10 15 13 12"
                behavior:WidthBehavior.WidthShareScope="Scope1"
                Content="Text"/>
        <Button Margin="7 2 14 11"
                behavior:WidthBehavior.WidthShareScope="Scope1"
                Content="Longer Text"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: +1 for the nice solution, even thought the OP asked for a non-code-behind solution. This might be the best solution if no pure-XAML are possible.

Comment: Thx. I couldn't find a pure-xaml solution and anyway, this is not code-behind (xaml.cs) but a separate new control class.

Comment: True. IMHO I would implement it the other way around: having a container that can assure that any of its children share their width or height (or both). We could also have attached property to specify which child are sharing size and which dimension (width, height or both). But I'm too lazy to do it, so feel free to do it in my stead XD

Comment: Indeed, that is another (good) solution and using attached properties to have a more grained control over this size-behavior is a nice idea.

Comment: This is not code behind solution, its a custom control and there's huge difference here. Avoiding codebehind is, that it cannot be used in resources dictionaries, or easily copy&pased to another solution, none of this is true for custom control. However, I would go with behavior attached to button, rather than custom control

Comment: @tomab No I've nothing against custom control. But the idea of having a behavior attached to the button is a really nice idea, as this may work directly with any other type of control. I only use them until today, do you have some links to point me to?

Comment: For how behaviors work msdn would the best docs to read. I'll attach a simple example which does the job you want using attached behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can also use `UniformGrid`. Simply set `UniformGrid.Rows` to `1` to achieve the same behavior of `Orientation="Horizontal"` :

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Button Margin="3" Content="{Binding PreviousButtonText, ElementName=CurrentControl}" Command="{Binding GoToPreviousPageCommand}"/>
    <Button Margin="3,3,8,3"  Content="{Binding NextButtonText, ElementName=CurrentControl}" Command="{Binding GoToNextPageCommand}" Visibility="{Binding IsLastPage, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibleConverter}, ConverterParameter=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Button Margin="3,3,8,3"  Content="{Binding FinishButtonText, ElementName=CurrentControl}" Command="{Binding FinishCommand}" Visibility="{Binding IsLastPage, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibleConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Button Margin="8,3,3,3" Content="{Binding CancelButtonText, ElementName=CurrentControl}" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: Doesn't work(and I already explained in my initial question why). Replace the "8" margins by something big(like 30) and you will directly see that the Button allow a fixed size for the Button + the margin, not only the width of the button(which exclude the margin)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to share the same value for some property, width property in this case? create style for it:

```
<Style x:Key="DialogButton" BaseOn="{StaticResource YourDefaultButtonStyle}">
   <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
</Style>
```

Or use some layouting panel, e.g Grid:

```
<Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedColumnSize="Button"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedColumnSize="Button"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedColumnSize="Button"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" />
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Margin="0" />
    <Button Grid.Column="4" Margin="0" />

</Grid>
```

EDIT: one more suggestion:
it's good if your buttons have the same width across entire app if possible, not just single view. Create explicit style with MinWidth specified.

```
<Style x:Key="DialogButton" BaseOn="{StaticResource YourDefaultButtonStyle}">
   <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
</Style>
```

All buttons with this style will have the same width, except the text exceeds the minwidth. This is how buttons in most dialogs works (e.g. in Visual Studio Options dialog, Save dialog, etc..)

Comment: Yes, but how to specify this width? Since it has to be the maximum of each button? not using the margin and having a grid could be an option, you're right

Comment: @How to specify this width? Look at the designer ;) its ok if you don't have multilanguage environment. And if you do have multilanguage environment, your approach could easily cause buttons to overlap, since there is high change that one of the translations will be too long and it affects all buttons. In this case, I would choose MinWidth approach

Comment: Yes, my remark was fro the style, since I told in the original question that the text of the button is dynamic. But your second option with having the Grid handling the size seems a good option

Answer (score 0):

Use implicit style?

But you need to know which Button has max width and binds it to the style.

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ButtonMaxWidth}"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button Margin="3" Content="11" />
        <Button Margin="3,3,8,3" Content="2222" />
        <Button Margin="3,3,8,3" Content="333333" />
        <Button Margin="8,3,3,3" Content="44444444" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: From where is comming `ButtonMaxWidth`? This should depends on the content of the biggest button.

Answer (score 0):

When I have `Margin`/`Padding` issues, I prefer to have an enclosing control element to deal with it independently of the original control.  One solution would be to imitiate the `Margin` with a `Border` with no thickness, no brush and a `Padding` with the desired Margin.

Then if the following solution, you must know in advance which `Button` will have the maximum width. Because we need to copy the `ActualWidth` of this `Button` to the `Width` of all the other.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Padding="3">
        <Button x:Name="MaxWidthButton"
                Content="{Binding Path=PreviousButtonText, FallbackValue=VeryLongTextThatIKnowItsLength}" />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Padding="3,3,8,3">
        <Button Width="{Binding ElementName=MaxWidthButton, Path=ActualWidth}" Content="{Binding Path=NextButtonText}" />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Padding="3,3,8,3">
        <Button Width="{Binding ElementName=MaxWidthButton, Path=ActualWidth}" Content="{Binding Path=FinishButtonText}" />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Padding="8,3,3,3">
        <Button Width="{Binding ElementName=MaxWidthButton, Path=ActualWidth}" Content="{Binding Path=CancelButtonText}" />
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the button with the maximum size is not always the same(as it will depends from the language by example)

Comment: Noted. The keyword to remember here is the `ActualWidth` property on `UIElement`, which would be needed in whatever solution you'll use.